# Install Gentoo via compilation on virtualbox?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, gentoo

Note that I am **not** asking how to install Gentoo on a Virtualbox VM.

My question is this: I have a slow machine ("Armpit"), and a fast machine ("Emperor"). Let's say I want to install Gentoo on Armpit. However, the compilation times on Emperor will be orders of magnitude less than those on Armpit. I therefore wish to install Gentoo using Emperor, but then "migrate" the system to Armpit.

Emperor runs Windows 8.1, however it is capable of running virtual machines with bridged network adapters via Virtualbox, so I can easily create a Linux environment on it.

Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about doing it, exactly?

Edit - useful info:

#### Armpit specs:

- CPU: Single core AMD Athlon 64 (2.2GHz)
- RAM: 2GB DDR2
- HDD: hundreds of GB (enough)

#### Emperor specs:

- CPU: Quad core Intel i5 2500K (3.4GHz)
- RAM: 8GB DDR3
- GPU: AMD HD6850 (FWIW)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [distcc](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Distcc) - you can distribute your compilations across multiple machines. So in your case the slow machine can use distcc to offload the compiling work to the fast machine.